# ggplot2 - Reset axis text after it's been set to element_blank

Tags: r, ggplot2

Once someone has set the `axis.text` to `element_blank()`, can the original setting be easily recovered. By original, I mean the ggplot2 original, not the original as of the moment that `element_blank()` was set. Basically, can is there something like `axis.text.x = element_default()`?

```
library(ggplot2)    

# A while ago in my code, someone might do this
x = ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) + 
      geom_boxplot() + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())

# Is there an easy way for me to do this:
x2 = x + theme(axis.text.x = default_ggplot2_value_for_this_item)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ggplot2's default theme is `theme_grey`. Here are *all* the defaults for that:

```
line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1,  lineend = "butt"), 
rect = element_rect(fill = "white",  colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1), 
text = element_text(family = base_family, 
face = "plain", colour = "black", size = base_size, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9), 
axis.text = element_text(size = rel(0.8), colour = "grey50"), 
strip.text = element_text(size = rel(0.8)), 
axis.line = element_blank(), 
axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1), 
axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1), 
axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "grey50"), 
axis.title.x = element_text(), 
axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90), 
axis.ticks.length = unit(0.15, "cm"), 
axis.ticks.margin = unit(0.1,  "cm"), 
legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA), 
legend.margin = unit(0.2, "cm"), 
legend.key = element_rect(fill = "grey95", colour = "white"), 
legend.key.size = unit(1.2, "lines"), 
legend.key.height = NULL, 
legend.key.width = NULL, 
legend.text = element_text(size = rel(0.8)), 
legend.text.align = NULL, 
legend.title = element_text(size = rel(0.8), face = "bold", hjust = 0),    
legend.title.align = NULL, 
legend.position = "right", 
legend.direction = NULL, 
legend.justification = "center", 
legend.box = NULL, 
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90", colour = NA), 
panel.border = element_blank(), 
panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white"), 
panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey95", size = 0.25), 
panel.margin = unit(0.25, "lines"), 
panel.margin.x = NULL, 
panel.margin.y = NULL, 
strip.background = element_rect(fill = "grey80", colour = NA), 
strip.text.x = element_text(), 
strip.text.y = element_text(angle = -90), 
plot.background = element_rect(colour = "white"), 
plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2)), 
plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"), complete = TRUE)
```

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. I'm guessing you copied this from the source, can you link me to where I could find the source?

Comment: just type `theme_grey` (no parens, no `?`) in an R console.

Comment: Note that if you actually try to reset it, you have to re-specify all of the arguments for `element_text`, like this: `axis.text.x = element_text(family = "", face = "plain", colour = "black", size = 12, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9)`.